# C# skips DispatcherOperation

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a big time-consuming task and I try to implement asynchronous methods in order to prevent the application from blocking. My code looks like this:

```
CancellationTokenSource _cts;

async void asyncMethod()
{
    // ..................   

    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var progress = new Progress<double>(value => pbCalculationProgress.Value = value);
            try
            {
                _cts.CancelAfter(25000);
                int count = await awaitMethod(_cts.Token, progress);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
        // .......
            }
            finally
            {
                _cts.Dispose();
            }

    // ..................
}

async Task<int> awaitMethod(CancellationToken ct, IProgress<double> progress)
{
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                sqlParser();                
                progress.Report(1);
                return 0;
            });
            return await task;
}

void sqlParser()
{
    string info = form1TxtBox.Text;

    // ................
}
```

Also, the program throws an exception, because sqlParser() updates UI thread, when it retrieves the text from the form. The solution is to introduce Dispatcher method, which allows UI update. I keep the body of awaitMethod the same and simply put sqlParser() inside of the Dispatcher:

```
DispatcherOperation op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    sqlParser();
                }));
```

Here happens something interesting: asyncMethod() even doesn't dare to call awaitMethod! However, if I put a breakpoint inside of sqlParser() and run debugger, then everything goes very smoothly.

Please, can somebody explain what I miss in my code? What kind of patch should i use to make Dispatcher work correctly? Or: how can I run my program without Dispatcher and without throwing UI-update exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution is to introduce Dispatcher method, which allows UI update.

That's never a good solution. Having background threads reaching directly into your UI is encouraging spaghetti code.

> how can I run my program without Dispatcher and without throwing UI-update exception?

Think of your background thread code as its own separate component, completely separate from the UI. If your background code needs data from the UI, then have your UI code read it before the background code starts, and pass that data into the background code.

```
async void asyncMethod()
{
  ...
  try
  {
    var data = myUiComponent.Text;
    _cts.CancelAfter(25000);
    int count = await awaitMethod(data, _cts.Token, progress);
  }
  ...
}

async Task<int> awaitMethod(string data, CancellationToken ct, IProgress<double> progress)
{
  var task = Task.Run(() =>
  {
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    sqlParser(data);
    progress.Report(1);
    return 0;
  });
  return await task;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. By the way, I was trying to follow your advises from "Eliding" article. The problem is if I want to run secondary thread without raising any exception or after reading all the necessary data from the UI prior to run the secondary thread, I have to rewrite the definition of numerous local variables. But, apparently, it's inevitable...